# Way to Instrument the web application or service deployed in the IIS

Tags: c#, .net, iis

Is there any way free ware or tools available to instrument the web app deployed in IIS. I need the following things to be captured.
1. Call Tree
2. Execution Times

Answer (score 0):

You can use following Profiling tools.

1. Visual Studio [Profiling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt210448.aspx) tools for getting the Call Tree and execution time.
2. Jet Brains [DotMemory](https://www.jetbrains.com/dotmemory/features/)
3. [AppDynamics](https://www.appdynamics.com/)

Comment: Thanks for your time. I have few clarifications on this. 1. Visual studio profiling tools needs Visual Studio IDE to be installed in the deployment server. 2. Jet Brains Dot memory is not a free version tool for tracing. 3. App Dynamics also a paid version i guess.